# GitHub настройка доступа по ssh в Debian 9

Tags: git, debian, ssh

Хочу склонировать репозиторий на свой удаленный сервер, git установлен, пользователь www создан и для него сгенерирован публичный ключ id_rsa.pub в папку /.ssh после чего ключ был добавлен вручную в настройки аккаунта,
права на запись в папку www пользователь имеет но при попытке клонирования по ssh возникает ошибка

```
Cloning into ''...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

Не понимаю что делать дальше, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255438/git-permission-denied-publickey-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите внимательно пользователя и права на `.ssh` и внутри:

```
drwx------  2 user user  4096 Mar 16 15:09 .
...
-rw-------  1 user user  3326 Mar 16 15:09 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 user user   742 Mar 16 15:10 id_rsa.pub
```

Лишние права тоже могут заставить ssh не использовать ключ.

Попробуйте `ssh -vvv`

Comment: -----rw------- 1 www www 3243 Aug 20 19:13 id_rsa
-----rw-r--r-- 1 www www  777 Aug 20 19:14 id_rsa.pub
-----rw-r--r-- 1 www www 1326 Aug 20 19:15 known_hosts Вроде так же все как у вас

Comment: что делает команда ssh -vvv

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36038548/13578169

Comment: а сам `.ssh` `.`?

Comment: drwx------ 2 www  sudo 4096 Aug 20 19:16 .ssh

Comment: 1) тут група `sudo` 2) а вы сами `git` из-под `www` запускаете? 3) ключ прямо там на сервере сгенерирован? 4) может при добавлении вручную скопированось криво

Comment: `git clone git@...` vs `git clone https://...`

Comment: все решилось двумя командами  eval $(ssh-agent -s) и ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: ключ под паролем был?

Comment: нет без пароля, eval $(ssh-agent -s) только не понимаю что такое

Comment: это ssh агент, который висит и выдает ключи; сам не знал, что он обязательно нужен; на десктопе он и так, получается, с сессией стартует, а на сервере я его сам запускал для другого.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась так, если у вас есть ssh ключ, публичная его чать добавлена в репозиторий и права на директории есть у юзера под которым вы в системе вам необходимо добавить ssh ключ ssh агенту https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent